# How to encapsulate database HTML response

Tags: php, html

In a PHP function I am grabbing random chunks of HTML from my MySQL database that may or may not be well formed. An example is:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" ><tr><td valign="top" style="font: inherit;">Heres something to display<br><br>Thanks,<br><br>
```

I am then returning this chunk of HTML from the PHP function and echoing what is returned onto the page into a `<div>` holder.

The problem I am having is that the above displays properly but because it doesn't have closing tags it is playing havoc with the DOM when it is displayed. I can't control how the HTML is formed because it comes from random email responses. My question is, is there anyway to encapsulate this chunk of HTML and cut it off from the rest of my page? Are there tags I can wrap this HTML in besides `<div>` that will ensure that regardless of how well formed it is, it will display but not interact with the rest of the page?

Comment: In the browser, do you want to see a table, or as the markup `<table cellspacing ...`?

Comment: The HTML will vary widely. In the above example it is acceptable to be seen as plain text. If the HTML is not completely formed then plain text is fine but in the case where the HTML does have proper markkup, Id like it to display as intended.

Comment: If the above is not possible then plain text display is fine as long as line breaks are displayed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the damage caused by running it through a DOM parser. Example:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML("<root>".$your_malformed_html."</root>");
$reformatted_html = substr($dom->saveXML(),6,-7);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am a newbie and haven't used a DOM parser but will begin reading about it now. Quick question: will that GUARANTEE that it will not destroy the page or is the only way to do that to convert to plain text and strip away all the tags? Is it not possible to encapsulate that chunk of code to keep it away from the rest of the tags?

Comment: It "converts" the stuff you throw at it into well-formed XML (rather than HTML, which would add `<html><body>...</body></html>` and stuff to it). This will ensure that it /shouldn't/ break the page, however you may get an empty result if it's too malformed.